# Get the client's computer name

Tags: php

I am getting the client's (website user's) IP address. Now I'd like to go one step further by knowing the user's computer name. So far, my research has not turned up anything to aid me in retrieving this information.

Is it possible to use the user's IP address, or some other means, to get my visitor's computer name using PHP?

Comment: what do you mean under "name". Got any term?

Comment: What Basically u need to do with Computer Name here? telling us the requirement of using "COMPUTER NAME" we might help u in any other way to accomplish ur goal

Comment: Ok, Basically i want to keep information of user and their computer configuration for some survey purpose. I want to know, what is the percentage of user of different Operating system with hardware configuration.

I want to mention this survey in my presentation.

Hope knowing user information is not an illegal matter.

Answer (score 5):

PHP 5.4+

```
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases. If the server is in internet and the visitor behind a router, you'll only get the hostname of the router, but not of the visitors computer.

Answer (score 4):

You can perform a reverse DNS lookup using [`gethostbyaddr()`](http://php.net/gethostbyaddr).

Note that this will give you the name of the host the request came from according to reverse DNS.

- It will not give you a result if reverse DNS isn't set up
- It will not give you the Windows name of the computer
- It will give you the name of the router if NAT is involved or proxy if a proxy is involved.

Answer (score 4):

This is all that you could get using just PHP (you may try these butIi dont think this is what you actually needed):

```
gethostname()
gethostbyname(gethostname())
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
$_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE']
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
php_uname()
```

Answer (score 3):

Not possible with plain php running on the server. It'd be a security/privacy issue to know details of the client such as computer name, mac address, contents of his drive.

You need some sort of application running on the client's machine in order to get this.

Comment: Exactly, I don't want to see his/her disk content or mac address. But  i want to know just computer configuration(processor's GHz, Processor's name, RAM capacity) he/she is using(configuration) and the Operating System.

Comment: All of these are of similar importance (i.e private data, can be used to tell one user from other) and are not allowed by the http spec & implementers. You'd need some kind of signed applet or flash or activex component which would get those for you and send them to your server via http. This would definitely require the user's consent.

Comment: The operating system can be estimated via the http user agent string.

Comment: You can force the browser to send the client's computer name via NTLM to the server, which then can be read by the PHP script: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43842041/251719
Maybe not the most easy way, but it is possible at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to the hostname (displayed for instance by the `hostname` command on linux) of the computer doing the request:

That information is not included in an HTTP request. (That is, it's impossible for PHP to figure out.)

You could do a reverse DNS lookup, but that's probably not what you want anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you could do is try to get a DNS name for the client.  "Computer Name" is a Windows made-up thing.  Just call the built-in function `gethostbyaddr()` with the client's IP address.  However, it won't always (hardly ever) work.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this by**

$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']

'REMOTE_HOST' - The Host name from which the user is viewing the current page. The reverse dns lookup is based off the REMOTE_ADDR of the user.

*Note:* Your web server must be configured to create this variable. For example in Apache you'll need HostnameLookups On inside httpd.conf for it to exist. As David mentioned you can also use . [gethostbyaddr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php)

> Pls go thru all the comments in the
>   url before actually using the
>   function.

Comment: Yes! I saw it in php manual. but it doesn't work. So, do you have any other option to see the name of client computer.

Answer (score -3):

Do something lik this:

```
     <?php
 //get host by name
 echo gethostname();
 echo "<br>";
 //get OS
 echo php_uname();
 ?>
```

Comment: This show the server hostname and OS not the client