# Website that fetches computername and model etc

Tags: php, asp.net

So I was wondering if it was possible to make an asp.net application that fetches the computer name, model etc from the connected user( the user who connected to the website) and then adds the model name to a string and inserts it into a picture.

or can I do this with php?

it is going to be an website for my organisation.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The data you can retrieve is limited due to privacy reasons. Host is always possible (although you can never be 100% sure that it's the "real" one). Read more in this previous question: [Get the client's computer name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003385/get-the-clients-computer-name)

Comment: This is true if you are purely going by HTTP Headers. However, a .Net app in an active directory environment can get much more information about the connected user via active directory. Think of a corporate intranet.

Comment: how would you do that? make a string or variable in c# and make sccm search for the user name and get the primary device and then the info from the device?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible getting the computer name, unless you're talking about the hostname. Fetching user-agent & os information is available, but the computer name would be considered a security issue.

**I'd suggest you read this**

https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/client-identification-mechanisms