# Python Flask request get visitor hostname ( not IP)

Tags: python, flask, dns

I am using this to get the IP of the visitor, I jsut wanted to know if I can also could get the hostname of the client :

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def home():
    REAL_IP = request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP', request.remote_addr)
    return render_template('home.html', REAL_IP=REAL_IP)
```

**Note** : I want to use python flask and not socket  :

```
socket.gethostbyaddr("IP")
```

I actually want to know the name of the laptop client not the router or any material if NAT is in place.

Comment: You'll have to do a DNS reverse lookup for the IP. They may take several seconds though, so I would recommend against doing it in-request.

Comment: This is the same discussion as this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003385/get-the-clients-computer-name